# MAUI: The content page and pop up pages are breaking in normal running

Tags: maui

I am facing a weird issue in my new MAUI project. When LIVE running in visual studio all of my pages are working fine. But when I open the app normally, the app is breaking on some of the pages, but no issue in LIVE running. The same pages are working fine in LIVE running. I can't debug this since the issue is in the normal running.

For reproducing this issue I have created a sample and uploaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wA5TKOum3xTgpkY9D6LEplVCCehpZT5f/view?usp=sharing). I have added one content page and pop-up page into it. Both pages will work fine in LIVE running and breaking in normal running.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to post code of your problem. Links breaks over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, this is an issue that only occurs in Debug mode.

For MAUI projects, Debug and Release will differ in some configuration properties. please refer to [Project configuration for .NET MAUI apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/deployment/visual-studio-properties) for more details.

Debug mode is recommended for you to use in Debug, if you want to test the situation of opening the app directly, use Release mode or [publish the application.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/)